# Search Google map polygon area from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

we are a non profit charity organization. Planning to open up some support centers. We have a MySQL database of our support centers as following :

```
booth_id
booth_name
latitude
longitude
coverage
phone
```

Detail:

```
booth_id
```

Numeric unique ID for support booth.

```
booth_name
```

Alpha-numeric name for every support booth.

```
latitude
```

Google Map latitude for each booth.

```
longitude
```

Google Map longitude for each booth.

```
coverage
```

Json formated Google Map polygon for each booth. This is the support coverage area of each booth.

```
phone
```

Phone number of each support booth.

---

What we are trying to do is; getting user location and search if he is within any support booth coverage.

Here is the data stored on `coverage` field:

```
{
  "0": "23.86998,91.20611",
  "1": "23.86599,91.20609",
  "2": "23.86597,91.2091",
  "3": "23.86563,91.21251",
  "4": "23.87021,91.21249"
}
```

[Which has this visual view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3k1ep.png)

Depend on the coverage area here could be more Json indexed objects. Each Json objects has `latitude` and `longitude` comma separated.

Now my question is how to find from MySQL if `latitude : 23.867467` and `longitude : 91.2074338` (it can be any value) within coverage area or within which booth's coverage area. Is this possible to make this search with MySQL query with help of MySQL function?

Please let me know, that will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use spatial functions provided by MySQL to store geometric data.

And then use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-within

Comment: Looks promising but don't know how to use with my data :( any example with my data will be really life saving.